# Run bitcoind as a service in windows

Tags: bitcoind, windows

#### Motivation

1. I don't want to have to have `bitcoin-qt` running.
2. I want the control and error handling capabilities that come when something is running as a service.
3. I want `bitcoind` to start when windows starts in the event of a server downage

#### Notes

I want to service `main` and `testnet`, which I think won't be an issue since afaik `bitcoind` listens on both ports. I'm just mentioning this for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Install

1. Download [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/download)
2. Comment out `#daemon=1` from `bitcoin.conf` with comment `#incompatible with windows service`
3. Shut down bitcoin-qt, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli to eliminate any confusion
4. `nssm install BitcoinCore "C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon\bitcoind.exe" -datadir=C:\Documents\Data\Bitcoin` (use your own path of course)
5. `nssm set BitcoinCore DisplayName Bitcoin Core`
6. `nssm set BitcoinCore Description Bitcoin node with a JSON-RPC server`
7. [image]
8. [image]

---

#### Test

1. You should be able to see 8333 connections in `netstat`
2. You will see `bitcoind` in your task list under Details
3. If you go to Service(s), it will take you to this service.
4. bitcoin-qt still works even in testnet mode
5. bitcoin-cli still works even in `-testnet`
6. Your app still works even in testnet mode

---

#### Running mainnet and Testnet both

Repeat the steps for install, but on step 4, use

```
nssm install BitcoinCoreTestnet "C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon\bitcoind.exe" -testnet=1 -datadir=C:\Documents\Data\Bitcoin
```

You will then be able to take requests for mainnet on port 8332 and testnet on port 18332