# Why can't I use Bitcoin-QT while bitcoind is running as a Windows service under NSSM?

Tags: bitcoin-qt-setup

Why can't I use Bitcoin-QT while `bitcoind` is running as a Windows service under NSSM?

Is there a trick to this?

For me to use Bitcoin-QT, I have to stop my windows service and then open it.

Or should I use a separate GUI tool other than BitcoinQT as a workaround.

Hoping for some help on this.

Comment: Did you try the steps shared in this answer? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/76740/run-bitcoind-as-a-service-in-windows iirc it worked for me last time I tried but it's been few months

Answer (score 1):

Both bitcoin-qt and bitcoind will, by default, try and use the same directory for blocks, chainstate, wallets, etc.
Both can't access the same files at the same time. The first will lock the data directory, preventing other Bitcoin Core processes from also using it, to avoid corruption etc.
If you want to use bitcoind, you can perform all the same wallet functions and more using the command line with bitcoin-cli, rather than using the GUI. Otherwise, shutting down bitcoind before opening bitcoin-qt is the only option.